# Auth0Mosca what's https://eugeniop.auth0.com parameter?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

So I'd like to use a json web token
based authentication for a mosca server
and I'm following this good article
https://auth0.com/docs/scenarios/mqtt

but I can't figure out what's  https://eugeniop.auth0.com

if I've to use it

or if I an use  a simply custom server

or if not  where I can find the {Your Auth0 ClientID}, {Your Auth0 Client Secret}

and what's the Thermostats connection

may be I miss something

but I'm stuck to this point

Can you enlighten me, please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just your Auth0 domain name, like `example.auth0.com`. You can find it in the top-right of the dashboard. My domain here is `panchaea.auth0.com`, but it would be `panchaea.eu.auth0.com` if I were using an EU account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so I'm tied to use a Auth0 domain ?

Comment: What do you mean by "tied"? You can create as many accounts as needed, all of them will have a unique Auth0 subdomain.

Comment: I mean tied = I have to use a Auth0 domain instead of my own domain

Comment: That domain is only used for the authentication and API endpoints, not for your application. If you'd like to use your own domain, you'll need a private instance of Auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/deployment